# Вывести в консоль фигуру из цифр

Tags: c++, c

Пользователь вводит размер фигуры сам и программа печатает в консоли прямоугольник следующим образом:

[image: Как должно получится]

Голову сломал, не могу понять как сделать это. Язык Си или с++(желательно си)

Comment: Циклами, циклами... Вот как сами рисуете - так и программе скажите. Да, в метках c# - это не си с четырьмя плюсами, это совсем другой язык, вы же простите с/с++...

Comment: тут важен не сам вывод, а логика программы... Инициализировать  два двумерных массива, выводить  их по строкам или еще как_решать вам...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решите для начала боле простую задачу - нарисуйте прямоугольник только единичками:

```
1111
1111
1111
1111
```

Теперь, повышайте сложность:

```
1234
1234
1234
1234
```

Теперь можно заметить, что в требуемой картинке происходит что-то вроде остановки счета, когда номер колонки доходит до номера строки:

```
1111
1222
1233
1234
```

На этом остается последний шаг рассуждений.

Comment: Я дошёл до этого, дальше не могу понять что делать

Comment: почему не можете? вот псевдокод : i = 1;   все n цифр = i;    while ( i < 4) {  
 выводить цифры;  последные  n - i  = , ++i; }

Comment: большой прямоугольник из пробелов, в него вписать два цифровых